# Proof that $\frac{n}{N}\cdot\frac{n-1}{N-1}\cdot\frac{n-2}{N-2}\cdot\ldots\cdot \frac{1}{N-n+1} = \frac{1}{{N\choose n}}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

Is there a sophisticate way to proof that:

$$\frac{n}{N}\cdot\frac{n-1}{N-1}\cdot\frac{n-2}{N-2}\cdot\ldots\cdot \frac{1}{N-n+1} = \frac{1}{{N\choose n}}$$

where ${N\choose n}$ denotes combinations.

When replacing $N$ and $n$ with values, both produce the same result.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We look for posts that have more than just a problem - please see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more info. The information that is missing here includes the source and motivation of the question, along with any attempts you have made. For example, although you are asking for a sophisticated way to prove the identity, you have not said if you know of any non-sophisticated ways to prove it, or even if you know the identity is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify the numerator and denominator.

$$\frac{n}{N}\cdot\frac{n-1}{N-1}\cdot\frac{n-2}{N-2}\cdot\ldots\cdot \frac{1}{N-n+1} = \frac{n!}{\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}}$$

Simplify by $n!$.

$$\frac{1}{\frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}}$$

The denominator is in the form $n$ choose $r$.

$$\frac{1}{N \choose n}$$

Comment: Your first equation is clearly false.  Also, you are confusing $n!$ with $N!$.

Comment: Ah yes, I accidentally wrote $N$ instead of $n$, thanks for pointing out. I’ve corrected the error.

Comment: The first equation is still wrong.  You should have an $N!$ in the numerator of the denominator.

Comment: Oh jeez, literally didn’t see that. :facepalm:

Answer (score 0):

This is a definition: $ {N \choose n} = \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!} $

Expand all factorials and simplify the tail (N-n)!